# Preserve NaN values in pandas boolean comparisons

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, missing-data

I have two boolean columns A and B in a pandas dataframe, each with missing data (represented by NaN).  What I want is to do an AND operation on the two columns, but I want the resulting boolean column to be NaN if either of the original columns is NaN.  I have the following table:

```
    A      B
0   True   True    
1   True   False   
2   False  True   
3   True   NaN    
4   NaN    NaN
5   NaN    False
```

Now when I do `df.A & df.B` I want:

```
0    True
1    False
2    False
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    False
dtype: bool
```

but instead I get:

```
0    True
1    False
2    False
3    True
4    True
5    False
dtype: bool
```

This behaviour is consistent with `np.bool(np.nan) & np.bool(False)` and its permutations, but what I really want is a column that tells me for certain if each row is True for both, or for certain could not be True for both.  If I know it is True for both, then the result should be True, if I know that it is False for at least one then it should be False, and otherwise I need NaN to show that the datum is missing.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Last value in desired output is not `NaN` ?

Comment: Use `numpy.logical_and`.

Comment: No, as long as I know at least one of the entries is False, I know that they are not both true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's use [`np.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html#numpy-logical-and):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[True, True, False, True, np.nan, np.nan], 
                   'B':[True, False, True, np.nan, np.nan, False]})

s = np.logical_and(df['A'],df['B'])
print(s)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3      NaN
4      NaN
5    False
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: Can you extend your answer for eq? 
`df.x = df.x.where(pd.isna, df.x == '1')`

Comment: @EvanBenn Looks to me that you are trying to do a `fillna`.   `df.x.fillna(1)`

Comment: I am trying for df.x = NaN if df.x is NaN else df.x == 1

Comment: Try this:  `df.x.mask(df.x.notnull(),1)`

Answer (score 7):

## pandas >= 1.0

This operation is directly supported by pandas provided you are using the new [Nullable Boolean Type `boolean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/boolean.html) (not to be confused with the traditional numpy `bool` type).

```
# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[True, True, False, True, np.nan, np.nan], 
                   'B':[True, False, True, np.nan, np.nan, False]})

df.dtypes                                                                  

A    object
B    object
dtype: object
```

```
# A little shortcut to convert the data type to `boolean`
df2 = df.convert_dtypes()                                                  
df2.dtypes                                                                 

A    boolean
B    boolean
dtype: object

df2['A'] & df2['B']                                                        

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     <NA>
4     <NA>
5    False
dtype: boolean
```

In conclusion, please consider upgrading to pandas 1.0 :-)